# Does the moon have all these powers?

Tags: biology, moon

Today, I was talking with a coworker and I was surprised to see that she strongly believe that:

- When the moon is closer to the earth, hair grows faster.
- The moon influences when a woman (or person with a uterus) will have their period.
- Pregnant people are more likely to give birth when the moon is full.

Is there any truth to all of this?

**Edit**: 
Here are some websites who support those claims:

- About period https://www.menstruation.com.au/periodpages/mooncycles.html
- About growth of hair: http://moonsign.today/hair_care_moon.html

<sub>If this is considered to be multiple questions, I am most interested in the one about the period.</sub>

Comment: This doesn't really meet the bar for examining "notable claims" that this site is intended for. https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/864/faq-must-all-questions-be-notable

Comment: @NuclearWang I haded a link about women period. I will try to find another about hair growing faster. But, in the meantime, is this link good enough?

Comment: Those are fairly common myths in Brazil and south america overall. It falls on that "a bunch of people believe in this wives tale" area.

Comment: The one about more babies being born on the full moon is very common. A quick Google search yields dozens of maternity sites with an article on the subject (which pretty much all say it doesn't work like that). It's notable enough that even [HowStuffWorks](https://health.howstuffworks.com/pregnancy-and-parenting/pregnancy/labor-delivery/births-full-moon.htm) has an article on the subject.

Comment: The one about more babies being born on the full moon also has an answer [here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/275/are-more-babies-born-during-full-moons).

Comment: The hair one - alongside several other Moon+Hair related myths - can be found [here](https://noticias.bol.uol.com.br/ultimas-noticias/entretenimento/2014/05/20/tire-proveito-das-fases-da-lua-para-cuidar-do-cabelo.htm) and [here](https://claudia.abril.com.br/cabelos/descubra-a-influencia-das-fases-da-lua-no-seu-cabelo/). Every site has its own variant about it, but the gist is overall the same - a specific moon phase adds this or that effect over the hair.

Comment: The period one was debunked [here](https://helloclue.com/pt/artigos/ciclo-a-z/o-mito-das-fases-da-lua-e-a-menstruacao). I'll leave the link here if someone wants to write a complete answer.